# document.getelementbyid inside onclick of an input element

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have a input radio element like this:

```
<input type="radio" value="" name="radiobtn" />
```

on click of this radio button I should be able to pass the value of radio button to js function, i tried like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio" value="" name="packages" onclick="callrest(document.getElementById('radio')"/>
```

but it is saying "undefined", please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this here 'this' refer to current element :

```
 <input type="radio" id="radio" value="" name="packages" onclick="callrest(this.value);"/>
```

Comment: It should be `this.value`

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` attribute to get value of the radio button

```
<input type="radio" id="radio" name="packages" onclick="callrest(this.value);"/>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/he6h4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` or `getElementById` function as you used.
but you were missing `)` syntax in calling function.

```
<input type="radio" id="radio" value="" name="packages" onclick="callrest(document.getElementById('radio'))"/>
```

Comment: `get` **Document** `ById`?